# Post jQuery variable on same file and receive with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I post jQuery data and receive on the same file without passing through the URL as a variable (eg. `test.php?data=xxx`).

For example here's the response.data that I can see in the console log.

```
function (response) {                       
    console.log(response.data);
},
```

I want to post that data and receive on the same file. I have tried following:

```
function (response) {                       
    //console.log(response.data);
    $.post(window.location.href, {json_data: response.data});
},
```

but when in the body of same file I print

```
print_r($_POST);
```

it does not display anything.

Comment: please add here the value that you have in response.data which you see in the console.  when i test this, i am able to see $_POST['json_data'] just fine, but i am putting a simple value in where you have response.data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that response.data is Type: *PlainObject* or *String*.  See more here on [PlainObjects](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#PlainObject)

**UPDATE**

[Here is a video that describes what this code sample does.](http://www.screencast.com/t/9t7w79Enj7B)

*Code Sample*

```
<?php
  if (empty($_POST)) :
    ?>
      Nothing was posted, please click there \/<br><br>
    <?php
  else :
    echo 'You posted: '.print_r($_POST['json_data'], 1).'<br><br>';
  endif;
?>

<a href="javascript:" onclick="fake_simple_response('simple string');">click here (simple string)</a><br>
<a href="javascript:" onclick="fake_simple_response({cat:'meow', dog:'woof'});">click here (plain object)</a>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function fake_simple_response (response) {
    console.log(response);
    $.post(window.location.href, {json_data: response});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You wrote above that you tested and it works. Can you post the full example?

Comment: Sure i'm updating my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use POST, one way is to create a form and submit it with jQuery.

```
<form id="form-id" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" value="hello world" />
</form>

<script>
$('#form-id').submit();
</script>
```